# NSLayoutConstraints programmatically

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I want to add constraints to a view programmatically.

This is what I did:

```
extension UIView {
  func bottomToTop(other: UIView) {
     self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     other.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: self,
        attribute: .bottom,
        relatedBy: .equal
        toItem: other,
        attribute: .top,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 0.0
    )
    superview?.addConstraint(constraint)
    constraint.isActive = true
  }
}


let label = UILabel()
label.text = "Lenaaaaa"
label.sizeToFit()
label.backgroundColor = .green

let label1 = UILabel()
label1.text = "Lena 2"
label1.sizeToFit()
label1.backgroundColor = .green

let uiView = UIView(frame: frame) (not zero)
uiView.addSubview(label)
uiView.addSubview(label2)

label.bottomToTop(label2)
```

Why do I end up with this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I end up with this?

Because your constraints are ambiguous. Once you add even *one* constraint that affects a view, you must describe that view's position and size in terms of autolayout *completely*. (And you must stop talking about `.frame`, as it is now effectively meaningless.)

Thus, you have said only

```
label.bottomToTop(label2)
```

But you have not said where the top of `label` is, where the left of `label` is, where the left of `label2` is, and so on. Thus the autolayout engine throws up its hands in despair.

You could easily have discovered this just by running your app and using the *view debugger*. It puts up great big exclamation marks telling you what your autolayout issues are.

Comment: Also your code is wrong in various other ways. For instance you should never say both `addConstraint` and `constraint.isActive = true`; they do the same thing, and the second one does it way better.

Comment: Plus your code makes no sense to me because it talks about a `uiView` that never even goes into the interface, so I do not understand why you say _anything_. If this is playground code, stop it; use a real project.